# i have error "eol while scanning string literal"

Tags: python

i dont know what is the problem im junior on python  programer what happened on my code i study but i dnt understand this

```
#fungsi coverage

def coverage ():
    print("[1] Kota Besar)
    print("[2] Kota suburban)
    kota = input("PILIH KOTA")
    if int (kota) == 1:
       frekuensi =  input("Masukan Frekuensi : )
       if int (frekuensi)<300;
                htower = float(input("input Tinggi tower : "))
                hpengguna =float (input("input Tinggi Pengguna : "))
                pathloss = float (input ("input Median Pathloss : "))
                logahre = math.log(1.54 * hpengguna, 10)**2)
                ahre =  8.29 * logahre - 1.1
                logfrek = math.log(frekuensi, 100
                loghte = math.log(htower, 10)
                pangkat = (-69.55-26.16*logfrek+13.82*loghte+ahre+pathloss)/44.9-(6.55 * loghte) 
                print ("%s"%pangkat)
```

> EOL while scanning literal

Comment: You are missing quotation makrs in both of your print statements `"[1] Kota Besar`, should be `"[1] Kota Besar"`. The same with the second print statement

Comment: Also in `input("Masukan Frekuensi : )`

Comment: thx for helpin me hehe in my own mistake

Comment: @daffafaiz I do recommend an editor with syntax highlighting. Look for example at the code colors in your question on this SO page. Literal strings are normally in red, statements are black. You can immediately see parts where is something odd.

Comment: in this site if red highlight its a somtghing odd in my sytax isn't  thx helping mee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many syntax issues in your code. Here is a working code, all are very minor things like double quotes, semi column, brackets

```
#fungsi coverage

def coverage ():
    print("[1] Kota Besar")
    print("[2] Kota suburban")
    kota = input("PILIH KOTA")
    if int (kota) == 1:
       frekuensi =  input("Masukan Frekuensi : ")
       if int (frekuensi)<300:
                htower = float(input("input Tinggi tower : "))
                hpengguna =float (input("input Tinggi Pengguna : "))
                pathloss = float (input ("input Median Pathloss : "))
                logahre = math.log(1.54 * hpengguna, 10)**2
                ahre =  8.29 * logahre - 1.1
                logfrek = math.log(frekuensi, 100)
                loghte = math.log(htower, 10)
                pangkat = (-69.55-26.16*logfrek+13.82*loghte+ahre+pathloss)/44.9-(6.55 * loghte) 
                print ("%s"%pangkat)
```

Comment: Please upvote if it works for you, Let me know if you face any issues. Compare line to line you will get our mistakes

Comment: eol means end of the line