# List the SNS topic using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

Im trying to list the sns topic using boto3

im using this code

```
import boto3
import pprint

response = client.list_topics(
    NextToken='string'
)


list_topics=[]
for each_reg in response['topic']:
    print(each_reg['topic])
```

but im geting this error

```
 File "kri.py", line 14
    print(each_reg['topic])
                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: Single quote missing at the end of 'topic'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i have error "eol while scanning string literal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034210/i-have-error-eol-while-scanning-string-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
list_topics=[]
for each_reg in response['topic']:
    print(each_reg['topic'])
```

and you need to import `sns` too.

```
client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1') # add your region_name here
```

Updated:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.list_topics()

for each_reg in response['Topics']:
    print(each_reg['TopicArn'])
```

Comment: I used ur code bro but im geting this error

botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ListTopics operation: Invalid parameter: NextToken

Comment: this is my code bro

`import boto3

import pprint


client = boto3.client('sns')

response = client.list_topics(
    NextToken='list_topics'
)

list_topics=[]
for each_reg in response['topic']:
    print(each_reg['topic'])`

Comment: this is because, you need to specify region, I have updated the snippet. Please check and let me know once.

Comment: I need to list my SNS topic bro, can u able me to provide a code bro ??

Comment: ok got it. Actually you are using wrong key. Check my updated code. This is working absolutely fine for me

Comment: Thank You so much bro.

Comment: Bro can we able to execute a specific Topic name ?

Comment: @Ganesh AWS You can ask a separate question and post what u have tried and tag me. I can try to improve your answer or can propose a solution for that.

Comment: kumer posted bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112336/list-a-sns-topic-using-boto3

Comment: @GaneshAWS It's showing Page Not Found for me, for the other question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
  print(each_reg['topic'])
```

You are missing a single quote.

Comment: if i correct that means i geting this error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kri.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = client.list_topics(
NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: I think this error is pretty self-explanatory. Client is not defined.

Comment: You have to create your client first with client = boto3.client('sns')